# C# Entity Framework code first migration error, no key defined though key is actually defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, key, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Entity Framework code-first approach. I am getting the following error when I run `Update-Database -script` in a blank database, after running `enable-migrations` and `add-migration`:

> standardvba.DataAccessLayer.LessonQuestion: : EntityType 'LessonQuestion' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   LessonQuestions: EntityType: EntitySet 'LessonQuestions' is based on type 'LessonQuestion' that has no keys defined.

`LessonQuestion.cs`:

```
public partial class LessonQuestion
{
    public LessonQuestion()
    {
        this.LessonQuestionDetails = new List<LessonQuestionDetail>();
    } 

    [Key]
    public int QuestionID; // Key is defined

    public int OrderNumber;

    [ForeignKey("ParentQuestion")]
    public int ParentQuestionID;  

    [ForeignKey("Lesson")]
    public int LessonID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ActionedBy")]    
    public int ActionedByUserID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public string Question { get; set; } 
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }

    [Required]  // Sets the CASCADE constraint, while creating table
    public virtual CourseLesson Lesson { get; set; }

    public virtual SiteUser ActionedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LessonQuestionDetail> LessonQuestionDetails { get; set; }

    public virtual LessonQuestion ParentQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

I tried options like deleting and re-creating the `Migrations` folder, but that did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Key needs to be `Public Property`. In your case, it is a field. You need to change it as following

```
[Key]
public int QuestionID{get;set;}
```

Comment: And before getting other problems, do the same (make property) for `OrderNumber` and `ParentQuestionID`.